# Using user input (python 3.7) in sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Hey guys I'm working on a task right now and I'm trying to add a login function which ask the user for their username and then sees if their input matches anything in the database. Excuse the bad coding it's my second year and I'm  in grade 10.

---

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('library.db')

cursor = db.cursor()

result = cursor.fetchall

def login():
    user = input("VAT IS YAH USERNAM: ")
    pastuser = user
    user = ("%" + user + "%")
    cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username LIKE " + user)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    if result == pastuser:
        print("VAT IS YAH PASWRD")

login()
```

Comment: And what's exactly the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite not providing the problem, your `SELECT` statement got syntax errors because it's missing `"` between the `%` signs on `LIKE` so change

```
user = ("%" + user + "%")
```

to

```
user = ("\"%" + user + "%\"")
```

Also you are comparing `result` with `pastuser` but result is a list of tuples with all the tuples returned from the `SELECT`, if you want to check only the first user encountered change

```
if result == pastuser:
```

to

```
if result[0][0] == pastuser:
```

or you can change the `fetchall` method to `fetchone` which returns a single tuple.

If you want to iterate trough all the users:

```
for u in result:
    ...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help it got rid of the syntax error but it's still not processing the code in the if statement. I will try and fix it but if you could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you use `fetchall` you are retrieving a list of tuples, containing every data returned in your select statement. As the return is a list with N tuples, you can't just compare this list with a single string, as the datatypes are completely different. To compare to a single string you need to access the specific string you wan't to compare. In my example i accessed the first tuple (the first `[0]`) in it's first item (the second `[0]`, because the username is your first column on your select), so that's the change you need to make in your code. Hope I made it clear